# Safari for Mac: URL bar empties after loading a set of pages from bookmarks

Tags: macos, safari, bookmarks

This of on Safari 14.1.2 on MacOS 10.14.6.

I have a Safari window open with several tabs, and I also have several bookmark folders pinned on my bookmark bar. I accidentally clicked on one of them, so all the tabs in my window were replaced by the pages in that bookmark folder.

I quickly clicked back and my previous tabs loaded again... except that all the URL bars were blank, so the pages obviously don't load. All those webpages were lost.

Has this happened to anyone else? Is this a bug? Is there any way to fix it or recover the lost addresses? Has this been fixed in later versions?

Comment: Unless the tabs were private you should find all the pages visited under History.

Comment: The new tabs should have opened to the right of your existing ones rather than replacing them. Too late now, but for next time...

Comment: @AivarPaalberg: yeah, well, but the problem is that the tabs had been opened for months. Trying to locate all of them in the History...

Comment: @Tetsujin: are you sure? That's never been my experience. Every time I've clicked on a bookmark folder, it's replaced all the tabs in my window.

Comment: Ah, sorry - opening a folder adds, one of those single button ones replaces. My bad.